# How to create a variable for chart js datalabel plugin formatter

Tags: javascript, variables, plugins, chart.js

I am trying to write a global formatting variable for chart js datalabels plugin across all the charts I create. Here is my attempt -

Global Variable:

```
var datalabels_format_sanssymb = {
    function (value) {
        if (value >= 1000000000 || value <= -1000000000) {
            return (value / 1000000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '');
        }
        if (value >= 1000000 || value <= -1000000) {
            return (value / 1000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '');
        }
        if (value >= 1000 || value <= -1000) {
            return (value / 1000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '');
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

And here is where I want to call the variable in the chart javascript:

```
plugins: {
    datalabels: {
        formatter: datalabels_format_sanssymb,
        font: {
            size: 10,
            weight: 'bold'
        },
        color: '#333333'
    }
},
```

This doesn't seem to work. Am I doing this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plugins.datalabels.formatter` should be set to a function. You are setting it to an object. Change your definition so it doesn't include the leading `{` and trailing `}`:

```
var datalabels_format_sanssymb = function (value) {
    if (value >= 1000000000 || value <= -1000000000) {
        return (value / 1000000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '');
    }
    if (value >= 1000000 || value <= -1000000) {
        return (value / 1000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '');
    }
    if (value >= 1000 || value <= -1000) {
        return (value / 1000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '');
    }
    return value;
}
```

See the [plugin documentation](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/formatting) for examples.